# Flutter : Drawer Only Opens Once and then Circular Progress Indictaor Shows Up if opened again

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have wrapped my Drawer with StreamBuilder<User?> so that I can access the current user profile details. But with this, I am facing a problem that the drawer opens only once and when tried to open again I only see a circular progress indicator. Is there any alternative to which I have implemented?  Thanks in advance. I am attaching a short gif of the issue as well as the code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/blocs/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/doctor_details_page.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  StreamSubscription<User>? loginStateSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    var authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context, listen: false);

    loginStateSubscription = authBloc.currentUser.listen((fbUser) {
      if (fbUser == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }) as StreamSubscription<User>?;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    loginStateSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 0.8),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 0.0),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: authBloc.currentUser,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data!.displayName!,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Welcome Back",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 20, right: 20),
                    width: size.width,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0x14000000),
                          offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          blurRadius: 15,
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                            child: TextField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              autofocus: false,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff107163), fontSize: 20),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'Search..',
                              ),
                              cursorColor: Color(0xff107163),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xff107163),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 25,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Category',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff363636),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 1),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text(
                              'See all',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5e5d5d),
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [
                        demoCategories("assets/images/tooth.png", "Tooth"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/brain.png", "Brain"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/heart.png", "Heart"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/bone.png", "Bone"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Top Rated',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff363636),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 1),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text(
                              'See all',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5e5d5d),
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          demoTopRatedDr(
                            "assets/images/leaf.png",
                            "Dr. Lata Grover",
                            "Homeopathic Doctor",
                            "4.8",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: authBloc.currentUser,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Drawer(
                elevation: 0,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: [
                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: Text(snapshot.data!.displayName!),
                      accountEmail: Text(snapshot.data!.email!),
                      decoration:
                          BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 1)),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.photoURL!),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            authBloc.logout();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Logout",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              authBloc.logout();
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.logout))
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget demoCategories(String img, String name) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff107163),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset(img),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Text(
              name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 13,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget demoTopRatedDr(
    String img,
    String name,
    String speciality,
    String rating,
  ) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DoctorDetailPage()));
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 90,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              height: 90,
              width: 50,
              child: Image.asset(img),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 17,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xffababab),
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: size.width * 0.25),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Rating: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  rating,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Please See For Better Understanding of the Issue]

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix to this issue. Instead of wrapping my Drawer with `StreamBuilder<User?>` I used `final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!`
Here is my final piece of code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/blocs/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/doctor_details_page.dart';
import 'package:login_page_animation/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  StreamSubscription<User>? loginStateSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    var authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context, listen: false);

    loginStateSubscription = authBloc.currentUser.listen((fbUser) {
      if (fbUser == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }) as StreamSubscription<User>?;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    loginStateSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 0.8),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 0.0),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: authBloc.currentUser,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data!.displayName!,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Welcome Back",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 20, right: 20),
                    width: size.width,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0x14000000),
                          offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          blurRadius: 15,
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                            child: TextField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              autofocus: false,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff107163), fontSize: 20),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'Search..',
                              ),
                              cursorColor: Color(0xff107163),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xff107163),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 25,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Category',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff363636),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 1),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text(
                              'See all',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5e5d5d),
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [
                        demoCategories("assets/images/tooth.png", "Tooth"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/brain.png", "Brain"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/heart.png", "Heart"),
                        demoCategories("assets/images/bone.png", "Bone"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Top Rated',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff363636),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 1),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text(
                              'See all',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5e5d5d),
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          demoTopRatedDr(
                            "assets/images/leaf.png",
                            "Dr. Lata Grover",
                            "Homeopathic Doctor",
                            "4.8",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        elevation: 0,
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(user.displayName!),
              accountEmail: Text(user.email!),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 212, 153, 1)),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    authBloc.logout();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Logout",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      authBloc.logout();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.logout))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget demoCategories(String img, String name) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff107163),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset(img),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Text(
              name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 13,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget demoTopRatedDr(
    String img,
    String name,
    String speciality,
    String rating,
  ) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DoctorDetailPage()));
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 90,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              height: 90,
              width: 50,
              child: Image.asset(img),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff363636),
                        fontSize: 17,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xffababab),
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: size.width * 0.25),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Rating: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  rating,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```